# Are these Toronto Chinese restaurants cooking live or frozen Yellow Fin Grouper?

Tags: fish, chinese-cuisine

Many Chinese restaurants in Toronto serve Yellow Fin Garoupa or Grouper — 黃鰭斑.  1. From pictures beneath, are they live and fresh? Or frozen?

2. Is Yellow Fin Grouper sold live and fresh? If not, frozen?

[Crown Jewel Fine Dining](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g155019-d8816349-i240369694-Crown_Jewel_Fine_Dining-Toronto_Ontario.html)

[image]

[Casa Imperial Chinese Cuisine](https://www.tripadvisor.com.my/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g155019-d817388-i375054383-Casa_Imperial_Fine_Chinese_Cuisine-Toronto_Ontario.html)

[image]

[Gold Mark](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Restaurant_Review-g181720-d8369089-Reviews-Gold_Mark-Markham_Ontario.html#photos;aggregationId=101&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=195494209)

[image]

[Century Palace Chinese Restaurant](https://www.zomato.com/toronto/century-palace-chinese-restaurant-markham-gta)

[image]

Comment: (before it gets removed) For the part specific to Toronto restaurants, I would try asking a Toronto specific like https://www.reddit.com/r/toronto/  or https://www.chowhound.com/tag/ontario

Comment: The yellow fin garoupa dwells in deeper, warm waters, which are far away from Canada, so I would be very surprised if they could bring the fish to Toronto alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that this fish was not frozen. If you were paying top dollar at a fine restaurant they may bring it in live, but the restaurant would tell you that.